# Resizing image using PHP GD and saving the image. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: mysql, database, resize, save, php-gd

I've used this code to detect the file type and use relevant image GD functions to resize and store images in the specified file location.

Arguments are defined as: **the original file location**, **file type** and **file name**.

File type and file name are fetching information from the `$FILES_[][]` variable.

However, this code doesn't seem to generate the resized image, but very well updates the new filename column in the database.

```
function resize_image($file, $type, $name) {
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
$newname = 'small'.$name;
  $newwidth = $w;
  $newheight = $h;

if($type == 'image/jpeg' || 'image/jpg')
{

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($dst, $newname);
}
else if($type == 'image/gif')
{

 $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
  $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
 imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
 imagegif($dst, $newname);
 }
 else if($type == 'image/png' || 'image/x-png')
{

$src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagepng($dst, $newname);
 }

else
 {
 die("Invalid file! Please try again!");
}

return $newname;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set new variables:

```
$newwidth = $w;
$newheight = $h;
```

using `$w` and `$h` which are not defined anywhere. You probably want to use `$width` and `$height` variables which you get by using `getimagesize`.